# VS 2022 - Change Full Property format in Quick Actions

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, visual-studio-2022

Is it possible to change the format of the Full Properties generated by the Quick Actions menu in Visual Studio 2022 from what it currently does:

```
public string Country { get => country; set => country = value; }
```

To how it used to be:

```
public string Country
        {
            get
            {
                return country;
            }
            set
            {
                country = value;
            }
        }
```

I heavily prefer the latter.

Comment: Please try Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Formatting > Wrapping, please uncheck "Leave block on single line". This seems to be able to solve the situation where get and set appear entirely on one line to a certain extent. Please let me know if this does not meet your requirements.

Comment: @wenbingeng-MSFT It didn't directly resolve what I was after, but it did the single line thing at least, and it also pointed me to where I was able to find the settings that modify the behavior of the Quick Actions functions I was looking for, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to wenbingen-MSFT's comment, I was able to find where the settings affecting the Quick Actions behavior for generating properties for a field reside.

For anyone else that might want to change this, Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Code Style->General->Expression Preferences->Use expression body for accessors and properties

Screenshot below:
[image: Screenshot of configuration]

Comment: Yes, this completely solves the issue. This is helpful. You can mark it so that it can help more people